# Nginx redirect won't capture URI

Tags: nginx

Basically I want the following redirections:

```
 oldwebsite.com/thehub > new.website.com (currently works but gives me new.website/?)
 oldwebsite.com/thehub/ > new.website.com (currently works but gives me new.website/?)
```

Note I want them to work with slash and without slash on `/thehub/` and `/thehub`.

Also, I want this to happen, which is the core problem.

```
oldwebsite.com/thehub/investors/any-article-here > new.website.com/investors/any-article-here
oldwebsite.com/thehub/something-here > new.website.com/something-here
```

```
 location ~ /thehub/(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^ https://new.website.com/$2 permanent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one capture group in your regex and its content would be placed in `$1` variable, not `$2`. You don't need a whole `location` block for this redirect, just use

```
rewrite ^/thehub(?:/(.*))?$ https://new.website.com/$1 permanent;
```

outside of any `location` block.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works. I was also wondering, how would I go about a scenario like this: If I want to redirect `site.net/faqs/3/what-is-equity-investment` to something like `new-site.net/faqs#what-is-equity-investment`?

Comment: @AliGajani I don't think this single example is enough to correctly write redirection rule, but for this particular case something like `rewrite ^/faqs/\d+/([^/]*)$ https://new-site.net/faqs#$1 permanent;` should work.

Comment: Thank you, so basically the format is `faqs/somenumber/sometext` and I guess I will have a try with what you posted. Remember I only want this to work for `/faqs/somenumber/sometext` type URLs and not `/faqs` or `/faqs/`.

Comment: @AliGajani If you want only `/faqs/somenumber/sometext` and not the `/faqs/somenumber/`, replace `^/faqs/\d+/([^/]*)$` with `^/faqs/\d+/([^/]+)$`.